# Set File header of ".txt" file in .Net

Tags: .net, file, encryption, header

Is it possible to store some special content inside file header of ".txt" file using .Net ? If yes how ? Please give me a sample code.

Comment: What do you mean by file header?

Comment: He probably means a "file header"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible. .txt files don't have a header. They are plain (text) files without any additional file structure.

If you need to attach additional information to a .txt file you might want to have a look at **[Alternate Data Streams](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763)** which are available when you are using NTFS. However, alternate data streams are a feature of NTFS only and will not survive a file transfer via another medium beyond a simple file copy (web streaming, sending by email, etc).

As your question is tagged with `encryption` it looks as if you are trying to store additional encryption information or a digital signature with your .txt file. In such a case it might as well be an option for you to have a look at container formats such as zip.